# How do I gain permission to put a file into /lib/firmware/?

Tags: networking, drivers, permissions, kubuntu

I just installed Kubuntu and it doesn't recognize my Wifi network because I don't have the appropriate driver. I downloaded the driver from another computer and transfered it with a USB, now when I try to move the file to /lib/firmware/rtlwifi I get the message "Access denied. Could not write to."

What should I do?

Comment: Use the terminal to move the file and prefix the command with `sudo`

Comment: `sudo cp somefile  /lib/firmware/rtlwifi` should do it.

Comment: ...if you are really really sure that the file is compiled for your release of Ubuntu and the proper architecture.

Comment: 1) you really shouldn't try to copy/install firmware files from another machine, 2) if you double check your syslog, you might find that what really happened is that it didn't find the specific firmware file that it was looking for first, but found others, as it kept on looking, and it eventually did load a firmware file.